# How to go around email forwarding

Tags: email, imap, forwarding

I have a problem with email forwarding that I want to overcome/go around. My university account has some sort of problem with forwarding. It just denies it. The people responsible have been trying to solve the problem for the past month and failed, which leaves me with no choice but to seek an alternative way.

In that context is there a way to setup a forwarding that is external to the mail server? I would normally just use Gmail, but my mail account is based on MS Exchange and it is IMAP only, which cannot be retrieved by Gmail. Is there something I can set up on my home server to retrieve mail and then forward it to another address?

Comment: FYI: MS Exchange will not allow automatic rules to forward e-mail to external accounts by default. This is a security policy and also prevents the risk of e-mail forwarding loops. It can be disabled on the server but this should generally be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MTA on your server (postfix, exim4, sendmail, msmtp) that is able to send outgoing mail, you could retrieve the messages from IMAP using `fetchmail` and forward them to your Gmail mailbox using `~/.forward`.

Comment: Can you direct me to a tutorial or manual on how to set up such a tool? Unless it is part of a standard Ubuntu distribution or package universe.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is not GUI-less you could leave Thunderbird running and use the Message Filters feature to autoforward all mail from that account.

Comment: I'm running a server Ubuntu distribution on an old machine. I can't do this.